# Selenium Webdriver returns None when trying to access text

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website and I can't seem to get the text in between two  tags as it keeps returning None. This is my code, could somebody tell me what is wrong?

```
uq = "https://my.uq.edu.au/programs-courses/requirements/program/2451/2021"                                                  
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/Connor/Downloads/geckodriver")                                            
driver.get(uq)                                                                                                               
groups = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/span[1]")
print(groups)                                                                                                                
print(groups.text) #This won't get the text between the span tags e.g. <span>hello</span>
```

Comment: Was the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

To get that text you'll need to click the parent element first.

However, you can avoid it with `.get_attribute("innerHTML")` and waiting for the presence of the element. Also, make sure you are using stable locators.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
uq = "https://my.uq.edu.au/programs-courses/requirements/program/2451/2021"
driver.get(uq)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Theory of Computing']>span:nth-of-type(1)")))
group = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Theory of Computing']>span:nth-of-type(1)").get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(group)
```

Prints: `COMP2048`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an action to get the value of the WebElement.

So you have to use this code instead:

```
print(groups.getText());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error when I use getText()

Comment: can you use get attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same for me. I have tried every way possible. Trying this:

```
print(speed.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

I get

```
<span data-download-status-value="NaN" class="result-data-large number result-data-value download-speed">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: <span data-download-status-value="NaN" class="result-data-large number result-data-value download-speed">&nbsp;</span>

Comment: in actual code , there are values for NaN and &nbsp.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).